ANSI and ISO projection
I would like to project views with the choice of the standard ISO or ANSI. Here is how I calculate and place my views :
Design CoDrawing; VectorView top;

top = new VectorView(0, 0, viewType.Top, scaleFactor, DrawingPanel.GetViewName(CoDrawing.ActiveSheet, viewType.Top)){ CenterlinesExtensionAmount = extensionAmount};
CoDrawing.ActiveSheet.AddViewPlaceHolder(top, CoModel, CoDrawing, top.BlockName.Replace(CoDrawing.ActiveSheet.Name, String.Empty));
displayedViews.Add(top);

The feature I'm working on is the projection of 2D views from a 3D object. And when I use the functions mentioned above, I get the 2D views according to the view specified: viewType.Top or viewType.Rear, ...However, I'd like to be able to choose how these views are projected and therefore be able to let the user choose whether to make a first angle projection (ISO) or a third angle projection (ANSI).
I tried to change the projection type but there is only orthographic and perspective.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to manipulate the projection angle to make it a first-angle or third-angle projection.

You are in control, place the view according to your preferred standard. Eyeshot views are created with a specific XY location and scale on the sheet.

The location isn't the problem but I want to modify the end result. When I need to specify the XY location, it's the middle of the future view.

Did you try viewType.Bottom instead of viewType.Top in this case?

Yes I got the two views but that’s not the point here. I want to change the way that the view is projected. Two sides can be different (holes and others things)

As far as I know, you simply need to swap top and bottom. Nothing else.
